# Multi view App Programatically

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to know if it is possible to make multi view app without using the Interface Builder.

I know how to make it with just using Xcode and Storyboards, but I just want to be able make it programmatically.

For example : If I have a `UIViewController` A (default view) with a `UIButton` and than I have another `UIViewController` B with `UIWebView` so when I click on the `UIButton` of `UIViewController` A I want to be able to display the second View (Without IB).

How can I set the action to the `UIButton` to display my second View (Without Interface Builder) ?

Comment: i have edit my question for clarity ;p

Comment: This is perfectly possible and can be found on google very easily. Have you done any research?

Comment: @Popeye thanks for your answer but yes i have search on google before asking question,I probably used the wrong term.usually I avoid asking questions to avoid the response type google is your friend.....

Comment: @IndiaNasirJones Don't worry I don't downvote. But I found this within two seconds on google. I only say cause there are a lot of users out there that will downvote if it looks like you haven't done anything. But they aren't sat next to you so they don't know, this is why I haven't downvoted cause I don't know so I asked. Best thing to do is just add what you have looked at show that you have done some research. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a target to your button:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in ControllerA, add this method:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.superview addSubview:controllerB.view];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On ViewControllerA

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

        UIButton  *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(50.0f,200.0f,60.0f,30.0f)];
        [btn setTitle:@"Next" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btn];
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    -(IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender
    {
        NextViewController *nxt=[[NextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nxt animated:YES];
    }
```

On viewControllerB

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 460)];    
       NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
        [webView loadRequest:request];

       [self.view addSubview:webView];
     }
```

Make sure that in AppDelegate.h should be navigation controller like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController*  navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.self.viewController ];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is not a place for adding subviews. Since OP is creating everything in code, the `loadView` method should be implemented in UIViewController's subclass.